# How to prevent starting of WPF-application after installation

Tags: wpf, installation, clickonce

I am publishing WPF-Applications in Visual Studio. After that I can install them by the oneClick - Installer.

After the installation the application starts. Is there a way to install the application without starting it after the installation? I am trying to create a installation routine for of up to 7 wpf-applications and it's a bit annoying when every application is starting...

Thx for help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This should help.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    if (MyCondition)
    {
        ShowSomeDialog("Hey, I Can't start because...");
        this.Shutdown();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        var window = new MainWindow();
        window.show();
    }
}
```